# Create a regex for following scenerio

Tags: java, regex

In Java, I have a constant string  "Transform for {0} unavailable" but when its come through the code it will look like following string

Transform for **c5d2f185503a11e68f4dd4bed9c2c707** unavailable

Transform for **c5d2f189503a11e68f4dd4bed9c2c707** unavailable

Transform for **c5d2f18b503a11e68f4dd4bed9c2c707** unavailable

Transform for **b3fe22d1543711e6afb7d4bed9c2c707** unavailable

Bold letters are random value (Only char and number). Can someone help me to create a regex by ignoring the random numbers?

Comment: Please clarify what you want as output and what you've tried so far.

Comment: [`Transform for [a-zA-Z0-9]+ unavailable`](https://regex101.com/r/mG7rM1/1) will help you find all such strings if this is what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex `Transform\s+for(.*)unavailable`

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/lY3jA5/1)

Java :

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Pattern p= Pattern.compile("Transform\\s+for(.*)unavailable");
    String s = "Transform for c5d2f185503a11e68f4dd4bed9c2c707 unavailable";

    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if ( m.find() )
    {
        System.out.println("Found match : " + m.group(1));

    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, Done that! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression should be something like `"Transform for [0-9a-z]+ unavailable"` depending if you only want to match lowercase or also uppercase characters. Your can test your regex [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).